# CSS :Before image is knocking text down

Tags: css, pseudo-element, text-alignment

You can see here in this fiddle that the text isn't sitting vertically center after I apply the `:before` pseudo:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bfkv8zsq/1/)

```
.explore:before {
    content: url('../images/explore.png');
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

I've tried to adjust the line height but it doesn't affect the text in any way.

Any ideas as to why it knocks down my text and how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;`

http://jsfiddle.net/bfkv8zsq/3/ Here you go!

Comment: No worries :) sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes